# CakePHP validation for multiple emails seperated by a comma

Tags: php, validation, email, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I would ideally like to validate the email field in my form to check each email is valid between each comma. However, if this is not possible or has to be bodged to achieve it then I can do this validation once I have posted the data.

The main problem I have is that CakePHP(v2.3) seems to automatically validate any field with a name of email. I've tried to just turn this off for this individual field, for this page and for the particular model but none of them seem to work.

My view has the following:

```
echo $this->Form->input('email',array('novalidate' => true));
```

I've tried this in my controller:

```
$this->Org->validator()->remove('email');
```

And i've also tried the following in the model:

```
public $validate = array(
    'email' => false
);
```

I'm sure it should be simple to just take off validation?

I have noticed that I do get an attribute on the input to say no validation but this is obviously ignored as it still validates the field:

```
<input id="OrgEmail" type="email" value="" maxlength="255" novalidate="novalidate" name="data[Org][email]">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the validation is made client side by modern browsers

try

```
echo $this->Form->input('email',array('novalidate' => true, 'type' => 'text'));
```

you can also specify multiple comma separated values, if you still want to use email html5 input type

```
echo $this->Form->input('email',array('novalidate' => true, 'multiple' => 'multiple'));
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html